# QlikSense expression to find average duration over a period of time

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I want to find the overall duration in hours over different periods of time. ie. once I add filters such as 'October' it should show me the overall hours for that month. I want to count duplicate lessons for multiple attendees as 1 lesson. ie. the duration spent to teach the subject.

```
 Date        Duration  Subject   Attendee
 1/10/2019     2:00    Math       Joe Bloggs
 1/10/2019     2:00    Math       John Doe
 2/10/2019     3:00    English    Jane Doe
 6/11/2019     1:00    Geog       Jane Roe
 17/12/2019    0:30    History    Joe Coggs
```

I want the overall hours spent on the subjects. This mean the duration total above should add up to 6:30, as the two math lessons should only count as 1 lesson (2 hours). How can I write an expression that produces a KPI of the overall learning ours, and then also allows me to drill down to month and date. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can suggest you to create another table that will contains the distinct values (im presuming that the unique combination is `Date <-> Subject`)

The script below will create `OverallDuration` table will contains the distinct duration values for the combination `Date <-> Subject`. This way you will have one additional field `OverallDuration` which can be used in the KPI.

The `OverallDuration` table is linked to the `RawData` table (which is linked itself to the `Calendar` table) which means that `OverallDuration` calculation will respect the selections on `Subject`, `LessonYear`, `LessonMonth` etc. (have a look at the `Math` selection picture below)

```
RawData:
Load
  *,
  // Create a key field with the combination of Date and Subject
  Date & '_' & Subject as DateSubject_Key
;
Load * Inline [
Date,          Duration, Subject,  Attendee
1/10/2019,     2:00,     Math,     Joe Bloggs
1/10/2019,     2:00,     Math,     John Doe
2/10/2019,     3:00,     English,  Jane Doe
6/11/2019,     1:00,     Geog,     Jane Roe
17/12/2019,    0:30,     History,  Joe Coggs
];

// Load distinct DateSubject_Key and the Duration
// converting the duraion to time.
// This table will link to RawData on the key field
OverallDuration:
Load
  Distinct
  DateSubject_Key,
  time(Duration)          as OverallDuration
Resident
  RawData
;

// Creating calendar table from the dates (distinct) 
// from RawData and creating two additional fields - Month and Year
// This table will link to RawData on Date field
Calendar:
Load
  Distinct
  Date,
  Month(Date)             as LessonMonth,
  Year(Date)              as LessonYear
Resident
  RawData
;
```

Once the script above is reloaded then your expression will be just `sum( OverallDuration )` And you can see the result in the pivot table below:

[image: Result Pivot Table]

The overall duration is `06:30` hours and for `Math` is `02:00` hours:

[image: Math subject selected]

And your data model will look like this:

[image: Data Model]

I like to keep my calendar data in separate table but you can add month and year fields to the main table if you want